# android surfaceview vs view resolution

Tags: android, view, surfaceview

I was able to display and move bitmaps on the screen in two ways. 1 using view, with invalidate()  to to constantly update the view and display the image  and 2, using surfaceview with surfaceholder.callback to lock the canvas and update the image

when I use view, I get a screen resolution of 1920x1080 on my Galaxy S4.

However when I use SurfaceView I get a screen resolution of 569x320.
in the surfaceview I was able to use the line getHolder().setFixedSize(1920, 1080)
however now all my bitmaps appear squished even though i called this line before loading any bitmaps.

how can I make the resolution and bitmaps appear as they do in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should call getHolder().setFixedSize(1920, 1080)  before setting the bitmap.